# Probability question on simple genetics

Tags: probability

Each person has two genes for hair colouring and each gene is either N or R. Each child receives one gene from each parent. You are redhaired if your genes are RR; if your genes are NN,RN or NR then you do not have red hair.

(i) It is estimated that 10% of the population of Ireland have red hair. De- termine the ratio of N genes to R genes in the population. What is the probability that an individual has the genes NN?

(ii) Neither Amy nor her parents have red hair. However Amy has a redheaded sister Zoe. Find the probability that Amy has at least one R gene.

(iii) Amy has a son Ben whose father does not have red hair. Estimate the probability that Ben has red hair.

Now I believe I've gotten the ratio in part (i) which is (316:684). Correct me if I'm wrong.

I have no idea how to approach the other questions. Is it possibly some probability distribution I am unaware of. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i) Lets let $n$ = the percentage of N genes and $r$ = percentage of R genes.  $$r=1-n\\n=1-r\\r^2=.1\\r=\frac{\sqrt{10}}{10}\approx0.316\\P(NN)=n^2=(1-r)^2=(1-\frac{\sqrt{10}}{10})^2\approx(1-0.316)^2$$
(ii) If neither parents have red hair, but they have a kid that is red-haired, they both must be $NR$.  They will produce offspring with genotype $NN,NR,RN,RR$ with equal probability, so Amy is either $NN$, $NR$ or $RN$ and thus has a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance of being homozygous $NN$ and a $\frac{2}{3}$ chance of being heterozygous $NR$.

(iii)I'll let you look at this part, but I assume we are in Ireland, so you can use the probabilities that Amy is heterozygous or homozygous from part (ii) and use the national probabilities to figure out what Ben's father is to make a probability square or tree to see what the possible outcomes for the son are.

Comment: One parent could be RR and another RN ? In order for Zoe to be RR.

Comment: But neither parent is red-haired, from the problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer